# How do I turn a hex into a color code?

Tags: colors, numbers, hex

I have a table of 24-digit hex numbers and I want to make it more readable, especially to see easily when two numbers are the same.

My idea was to do some operation on the long number to obtain a 6-digit hex number, that I will use as a color code. That way if the same number appears twice it'll be the same color.

One of the requirements is that two following numbers must have different colors. It doesn't have to be a completely different color (a different shade is fine), but that means I can't just truncate or use something that loses too much precision.

Ideally it would look like this:

> f(x588f0c494b9dcb29889e8d8c) = x2620d9
>
> f(x588f0c494b9dcb29889e8d8d) = xbadb57

How would you do this ?

---

I imagine there are already well-known techniques to get a *n*-digit number from a *n+m* digit number, but I don't know the name of the procedure, and I can't find anything without proper keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that doesn't give similar colors to close values.

I square the number and took the last 6 digits. That allows to avoid loops and recurring patterns. This way,

`58934c41080fe234dab7038a` is `#588664` and

`58934c41080fe234dab7038b` is `#c68d79`.

However, the color code of `5834...38a` and `5934...38a` are the same, but if it's not a problem to you it can be a strength because this way, you don't have to square huge numbers. The square of `b7038a` and `58934c41080fe234dab7038a` end with the same 6 numbers, so you can trim them before doing expensive calculations.

I'm still up for a more general answer if anyone has that.